# AJAX sending data to backend C# issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

Presently I am having the issue of trying to pass information back to the behind code, in this case a user selected name from a list. I have tried setting the data VN to an object and passing that, but that did not work either. Presently it seems to never send it to the behind code as it errors out instead. An example value for VN is: "Location1 Building"

This worked fine when the data part of the AJAX call wasn't used and the query was hardcoded into the behind code. I believe I am misunderstanding exactly how this functions. I have read over 8 similar threads but the fixes on those didn't quite work here either and lead to errors also listed below.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$("#btnClient_Report").click("click", function CallService() {
  var Cn = document.getElementById('client_input'); 
  var VN = Cn.value;
    
    
    
        alert("C1 Name: " + VN);
    $.ajax({
            traditional: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: '/ClientChart.aspx/Getdata',
            data: JSON.stringify(VN), 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (msg) {
                alert("Success: " + msg.d);
                CCData = msg.d;
                
                bindClientChart();
            },
            error: function(ermsg){
                alert(ermsg.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
```

**BEHIND CODE - C#**

```
[WebMethod]
 public static string[] Getdata(string VN) //test the connection and rerieve data requested. 
        {
            var loc_name = VN;
   
            //connect to DB and query more info.
```

At present the error is **"Cannot convert object of type \u0027System.String\u0027 to type \u0027System.Collections.Generic/IDictonary'2..."**

though attempting to change the ajax data to VN from `JSON.stringify(VN)` leads to
**"INVALID JSON Primitive"** error.

Attempting to change VN to a simple object like `var VN = { ID:[Cn.value]};` leads to a similar error.

The jquery $.AJAX function documentation says is accepts type string, so I would like to learn about how I am messing up and understand this better. Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: have tried data: { VN: $("#client_input").val() },. Got error: invalid JSON primitive.

Answer (score 0):

After trial and error I learned my mistake was that the ajax data line needed to be:

data: '{VN:"' +  $("#client_input").val() + '"}',

Inserting the  string  alone doesn't work properly as it needs the identifier even if you try passing a string as the same identifier name.  Hop this may help someone in future learn from my foolish mistake

Comment: Yes, the parameters variable names you use in the c# function have to match the jason string variables. Worse yet, you have a variable name with  space "Name C1", and i would not as a general rule try to use variable names with a space. You can even strong type, and pass a integer from js (and it will not have quotes around the value, and .net will strong type this conversion for you. So really, this comes down to ensuring you use the same variable name, and also avoid spaces in such variable names.  so the basic concept here is that variable names in your c# have to match the json names.

Comment: ah the name c1 was an alert popup to proc so I would see where it was hitting pretty quick and the value stored in VN, not a variable. In this case it was that I thought that sending "data: VN" would meet the naming conventions, but my brain was mixed up as that would be sending the value of VN not actually anything called VN. So labeling it "{VN: value}" makes sense when figured out, I just took a bit to figure it out. Thank you for the reply!

Comment: You are 100% correct - my wrong, my mistake. You  have a great day - good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Do Something like this to Pass string to method..

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ClientChart.aspx/Getdata",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: "{'VN':'" + VN + "'}",
                async: true,
                cache: true,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                alert("Success: " + data.d);
                bindClientChart();
            },
            error: function(ermsg){
                debugger;
                alert(ermsg.d);
            }
        });
```